# Python String without 'quotes' within an overall string

Tags: python

I want to create the following json request out. But the timestamp cannot have 'quotes' there. Been trying to fix the message string with no success...... Help!

```py
msg_1 = \
    {
      "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
      "id" : 833,
      "method" : "public/get_tradingview_chart_data",
      "params" : {
        "instrument_name" : "" + str(instr_) + "",
        "start_timestamp" : "" + str(1554373800000) + "",
        "end_timestamp" :  ""+ str(1654373800000) + "",
        "resolution" : "1440"
      }
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve

```py
{
  'jsonrpc': '2.0',
  'id': 833,
  'method': 'public/get_tradingview_chart_data',
  'params': {
    'instrument_name': 'ETH-12AUG22',
    'start_timestamp': 1554373800000,
    'end_timestamp': 1654373800000,
    'resolution': '1440'
  }
}
```

But I keep getting this

```py
{
  'jsonrpc': '2.0',
  'id': 833,
  'method': 'public/get_tradingview_chart_data',
  'params': {
    'instrument_name': 'ETH-12AUG22',
    'start_timestamp': '1554373800000',
    'end_timestamp': '1654373800000',
    'resolution': '1440'
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use the `json` library to convert your `dict` to the string you want?

Comment: Please include the code that is giving you the current results.

Comment: Why are you adding empty strings to both sides of your strings? It will have no effect

Answer (score 0):

Strings in python are surrounded by either single quotation marks, or double quotation marks. If you would like just the integer value, without quotes:
Try using int() instead of str().

example:

```
int(1554373800000)
```

Comment: The number is already an integer, so I don't see why we needo to cast it. Just need to do `"start_timestamp": 1554373800000,`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply typecast your string to int using

```
int("Number in String Datatype")
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using `str()` when you mean not to.

I don't know what `instr_` is, but just in case its an object with a `__str__()` method I'll leave that one in. The others don't need it:

```py
msg_1 = \
    {
      "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
      "id" : 833,
      "method" : "public/get_tradingview_chart_data",
      "params" : {
        "instrument_name" : str(instr_),
        "start_timestamp" : 1554373800000,
        "end_timestamp" :  1654373800000,
        "resolution" : "1440"
      }
```